# weird characters displayed during serial communication OSX

Tags: linux, macos, serial-port

I have tried communicating via serial (OSX w/ prolific drivers -> USB RS232 adapter -> Tx,Rx and GND pins on device serial ttl port) to a device and done so **successfully** using

```
screen /dev/tty.usbserial 115200 8N1
```

I get to log in and use it as if I was SSH or TelNetted in...

However whenever I try to go into system recovery mode (holding CTRL+1) while the device is powering on, it starts displaying weird characters and until I close the screen session it will continue showing weird characters:

[image]

Of course when we tried doing the same thing on my boss' macbook running windows and PuTTY and everything worked fine, even in system recovery mode; characters were displayed properly.

What gives? Id like to learn the intuition to use because up till now I concluded that since I can bot into the system and see characters normally *everything* about the connection should be fine and its must have been the recovery partition that was broken. This was wrong of course...

Niko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno if it is a OSX problem,

I had similar problems before. I fixed it either by changing the Baud rate of the com ports or by making sure the Ground on the circuit is the same as the ground of the supply.