# Can serially transmitting faster baud rate ruin a device?

Tags: macos, bash, serial-port, home-automation

I have a TV that accepts 9600 8N1 serial transmission to control it.

I have a USB to serial cable that I use to control this TV with my computer (to control things such as power off, power on, volume, etc). I just got the cable yesterday and I got everything to work. Generally by installing the drivers and going:

```
stty -F /dev/tty.usbserial 9600
echo -ne '\x08\x22\x01\x00\x01\x00\xd4' > /dev/tty.usbserial
```

^^ the above echo line turns the volume down on my tv by sending hex string serially. (I have a Samsung smart-tv)

Now I might have done the second line without the first a few times when opening a new terminal window. So I think it may have transmitted way faster than 9600 to the tv. And now my TV doesn't accept ANY type of serial commands, not even the 9600 anymore. Is there a chance I could've fried my tv by transmitting in a faster baud rate?

Comment: Did you try power-cycling your TV? (You might want to wait more the 30 secs even) OR is the a reset switch? Not really a programming Q, but good luck.

Comment: No, a mismatched baudrate should not harm RS-232 interfaces.  In fact RS-232 specifies rather robust ports, e.g. they have to be tolerant of miswired pins and ESD.  Double check you connections.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264386/usb-serial-communication-giving-strange-output/29270320#29270320